# sorting vector elements of a list by certain rules

Tags: sorting

I want to write code that sorts out a list by some specific rules.
The rules are logically straightforward, but I am having trouble coding it.

This is my input list

```
{{223, 1, 415, -13}, {313, 9, 505, -26}, {177, 369, -9, 13}, {308, 184, 26, 500}, {222, 414, -1, 33}, {358, -184, 550, -33}}
```

and I want to turn this into

```
{{223, 1, 415, -13},{177, 369, -9, 13}, {313, 9, 505, -26}, {308, 184, 26, 500}, {358, -184, 550, -33}, {222, 414, -1, 33}, {223, 1, 415, -13}}
```

Here are the rules.

Rule #1, ignore the first component of each element (223, 177, 313, ... don't do anything).

Rule #2, the second element(vector) has a component with the negative sign of a component of the first element. (Element 1 has 1, 415, -13. Thus element 2 should have either -1, -415, or 13). Likewise, fill out the following slots.

Rule #3, add another element that is the same as element 1 at the end.

Could anyone help me write a code that does this sorting, please?
Thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly I think there's a typo: the first list should be `{{223, 1, 415, -13}, {177, 369, -9, 13}, {313, 9, 505, -26}, {308, 
  184, 26, 500}, {222, 414, -1, 33}, {358, -184, 550, -33}}` right?

Comment: @bmf If you are talking about the initial alignment, it doesn't matter at all. I want to end up with the second list regardless of the initial alignment. Thank you anyway though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using the `Graph` functionality of Mathematica (note that this approach might not scale really well to long lists):

```
list = {{223, 1, 415, -13}, {313, 9, 505, -26}, {177, 369, -9, 13}, 
        {308, 184, 26, 500}, {222, 414, -1, 33}, {358, -184, 550, -33}};

allowedPairs = 
 UndirectedEdge @@@ 
  Select[IntersectingQ[#[[1, 2 ;;]], -#[[2, 2 ;;]]] &]@
   Subsets[list, {2}]
(* {{223, 1, 415, -13} <-> {177, 369, -9, 13}, {223, 1, 415, -13} <-> {222, 414, -1, 33},
    {313, 9, 505, -26} <-> {177, 369, -9, 13}, {313, 9, 505, -26} <-> {308, 184, 26, 500},
    {308, 184, 26, 500} <-> {358, -184, 550, -33}, {222, 414, -1, 33} <-> {358, -184, 550, -33}} *)

cycle = FindHamiltonianCycle[Graph[list, allowedPairs]][[1]]
(* {{223, 1, 415, -13} <-> {177, 369, -9, 13}, {177, 369, -9, 13} <-> {313, 9, 505, -26},
    {313, 9, 505, -26} <-> {308, 184, 26, 500}, {308, 184, 26,500} <-> {358, -184, 550, -33},
    {358, -184, 550, -33} <-> {222, 414, -1, 33}, {222, 414, -1, 33} <-> {223, 1, 415, -13}} *)

result = Append[#, Last@#] &[First /@ cycle]
(* {{223, 1, 415, -13}, {177, 369, -9, 13}, {313, 9, 505, -26},
    {308, 184, 26, 500}, {358, -184, 550, -33}, {222, 414, -1, 33}, {222, 414, -1, 33}} *)
```

What the code does:

1. Generate a list of all pairs of elements that can be adjacent in the list. To do this, we check whether the last three elements of one vector (`#[[1,2;;]]`) intersect with the last three elements of another vector (`#[[2,2;;]]`). We then convert the list into a list of graph edges by applying [`UndirectedEdge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UndirectedEdge.html).
2. Use [`FindHamiltonianCycle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianCycle.html) to find a route through all the vectors. Note that any such cycle will be a valid sorting of your list: Elements coming after each other in the cycle are joined by an edge, which only happens if they follow your rule
3. Post-process the cycle into the format you want, so we only keep the first element of each edge used, and append the first element again at the end.

Comment: Wow......Sooooooo impressive. I am not fully getting the whole details yet though because some commands are completely new to me, it looks so clever. Thank you very much!